# Open jquery.dialogextend at the top right

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I am working on a jquery.dialogextend.js, found it at: http://www.jqueryscript.net/other/jQuery-jQuery-UI-Dialog-Enhancement-Plugin-dialogextend.html

I am not really a front-end developer and my css is weak, how do I get it to open at the window top right (or left if I choose)?

Thanks for any help.
Jack

Ps. What I am aiming for is a modal that overlays content, auto-grow with more or less content, can be moved and minimized (to my location of choice) and at the end of the day I will be adding and removing content all the time via an ajax call.